# How do I prove that this function between matrix spaces is continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, continuity

Let $E_A$ be the elementary matrix such that the $(1,1)$ entry of the $n \times n$ identity matrix is replaced with $\frac{1}{\det(A)}$

Define $h: GL^+(n, \mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for $A\in GL^+(n,\mathbb{R})$,

$h(A)=AE_A$.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: there was a typo, which is now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication $\mu$ of matrices is continuous and $\det$ is continuous too. From the continuity of $\det$ it follows that the maps $A\mapsto A$ and $A\mapsto E_A$ are continuous. And your map is $A\mapsto\mu(A,E_A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Both the determinant and matrix multiplication are continuous mappings, hence their composition is as well.